# Alerts and Formulas in DTDL models in Azure Digital Twins

Tags: azure-digital-twins

How to write Alert Conditions and Formulas in DTDL models in Azure Digital Twins, I can specify Property, Telemetry type, but is there any way to specify Alert Conditions and Formulas in DTDL models in Azure Digital Twins?

Comment: Linking Q&A post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/680210/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ADT does not natively support computational expressions in DTDL models. However, you can configure ADT to emit events during twin change or lifecycle events, which can then be handled by Azure Function event handlers that contain expressions.

There is feature request which has been considered for implementation in 2022 here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a78b15a2-f124-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0